# Fade in page with jquery after css animation completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a screen split in two halves, and depending on which side you click they are suppose to slide open like curtains and then fade in another page. I have done the animation with css and use jquery to added the appropriate class on the click event.

the issue im having is how do i get the new page to fade in after the css animation has completed?

this is my jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.container').fadeIn();

    /*-- Splash Screen Settings --*/
    var btn = $('.lang-box a');

    btn.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('lang-eng')) {

    $('.side-left').addClass('slide-left');
    $('.side-right').addClass('slide-right');
    }

    if($(this).parent().hasClass('lang-afr')) {
    $('.side-left').addClass('slide-left');
    $('.side-right').addClass('slide-right');
    }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The FadeIn function has a callback you can use as follows:

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

```
$(".container").fadeIn({ done: function() { // Fade rest of page in } });
```

Comment: Now i have to ask, what is difference between done and using complete callback here?

Comment: No, the container fade in is not the issue. as i stated above depending on the click function I add a CSS class that animates the two halves out of the screen view once this is done i want to fade in a new page.

Comment: @GavinWood then i guess you are looking for ontransitionend event